# Saving connection parameters in an RDP file

Tags: password-management, remote-desktop, remote-server, rdp

For connecting to a remote Windows Server 2008 I use a standard Windows 7 RDP remote desktop connection. In an RDP dialog there is an option to save connection parameters to an RDP file to use it later for a quick connection.

**Is it safe to save connection parameters (IP address, login, password) in an RDP file?**
 The computer is private, so I mean not the physical security but rather a chance for the parameters to be stolen by a malicious software.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aside from real people actively using your computer via physical access or remote administration: It is likely that a malicious software, which is able to read the saved password, has sufficient possibilities to read the password from the connection dialog as you type it in.

This approach is likely a bit more work for the author of the malicious software and it won't allow access to old unused RDP connections through.